# Breeze.js How to display Validation Error Message

Tags: breeze

during Save changes, there are instance when validation is failing, but how do i get back and display the actual Error Message. The saveFailed function is executed, but i want more details information, about what validations failed and those individual error emssages

```
 function saveChanges() {
       if (manager.hasChanges()) {
           manager.saveChanges()
               .then(saveSucceeded)
               .fail(saveFailed);
       } else {
           alert("Nothing to save");
       };
   };


   function saveSucceeded() {
       alert("changes saved successfully");
   };

   function saveFailed(error) {
       alert("Error while saving changes" + error.message);
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the TODO sample that is provided with the breeze download.

The dataservice.js clearly shows you how to catch and display validation errors.

Comment: This is only partially true, in my opinion. The TODO sample doesn't show how to correlate entity errors to form elements... which, I suppose, would be quite complicated. But my pea brain hoped it would be easier when I first started learning how Breeze handles data annotation exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

The 'error' object returned by the fail handler, should contain additional details, depending on the error.  The following properties should always be there

error.message       - the error message
error.status        - http error code - usually a 400 or 500 code
error.detail        - any details relevant to the error
error.XHR           - the raw XML HttpResponse object
error.responseText

For validation errors, right now they appear in the error.message, but we are looking at breaking them out in a cleaner fashion, possibly into another property. But for now they will appear in the error.message.